# Relative path to django static file

Tags: python, django

I am trying to find a way to read a JSON file from static files without hardcoding the path to the file.

```
   def value_setup():
       with open('path/to/static/config/species.json') as f:
           data = json.loads(f.read())

       values = data["value"]
       return values
```

Is there a way to open this file with just a relative path from the static folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your STATIC_ROOT and STATICFILES_DIR are well configured you can use the [finder's module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#finders-module) to do that. Just make shure you don't have multiple files with the same path after static root.